# php merge two JSON arrays into one object

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I'm trying to merge two different `json` arrays into one object. The `json` arrays have different data (in terms of the data itself and the structure):

```
datafortable = [{"name": 3,"amount": "1190042293","category": "cars"}]
dataforchart = [{"name": 3,"amount": "5801"}]
```

What I would like to get is something like this:

```
datafortableandchart = {
    "datafortable": [
        {
            "name": 3,
            "amount": "1190042293",
            "category": "cars"
        }
    ],
    "dataforchart": [
        {
            "name": 3,
            "amount": "5801"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then, in `javascript` I would like te be able to refer to the different `json` arrays like this:

```
dataprovider: datafortableandchart.datafortable
```

Is this possible?

Comment: datafortable .concat(dataforchart );

Comment: @dexter Do you want to merge arrays by js or php?

Comment: @splash58 I would like to get this done with php

Comment: @dexter `echo json_encode(array_map('json_decode', compact('datafortable', 'dataforchart')), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);`

Comment: @splash58 this gives me `[]`.

Comment: @dexter https://eval.in/916737

Comment: @splash58 forgot to put the arrays between `''`. Problem solved now. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First convert them to array then use `array_merge` to merge to arrays and again `json_encode` them

```
json_encode(array_merge(json_decode($datafortable , true),json_decode($dataforchart , true)))
```